# Как правильно в данном предложение употребляется "по-другому" с дефисом или без?

Tags: предлоги

По другому в данном случае не получится.

Answer (score 1):

Варианты для **заданного** предложения:

(1) Надо этой дорогой идти. ***По-другому** (= иначе) в данном случае не получится.* Дефисное написание.

(2) Надо по этому пути идти. ***По другому (пути)** в данном случае не получится.* Неполное предложение. Но **дефисное** написание тоже возможно.

**Пояснение**

1. Обратим внимание на  то, что [словаре](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B5&mode=slovari&l=1&dicts%5B%5D=42) местоимение ***другой*** может использоваться в качестве **самостоятельного существительного**, но при этом имеет ограниченный круг значений (**кто-л. иной, посторонний**): Не обращай внимания на других. При других молчит и дичится. В таком смысле слово нельзя использовать в этом предложении.
2. Соответственно, получаются **два варианта**: (1) дефисное написание **наречия**; (2) раздельное написание местоименного прилагательного в **неполном** предложении.

Answer (score 0):

Не имея контекста, трудно сказать.   Возможно как раздельное написание, так и с дефисом.

Ср.: Сегодня я решила пойти на работу по другому пути.
Ваня хотел посмотреть мультики, но по другому каналу шли только фильмы.

Comment: С констекстом, в данном случае с дефисом? Студенты в этих ситуациях должны поступать так, как разъясняют преподаватели. По-другому не получится.

Comment: Серж, почему вы не обособили деепричастный оборот в начале?

Comment: А где здесь студенты, которые всем должны? Долги у нас только перед словарем РАН. Открыл страничку и слушай "разъяснения".

Comment: Максим, писал быстро, вот и не не заметил.

Comment: Безусловно с дефисом! Наречие. Не получится поступать как? По-другому.

Comment: @Sharon, не понял, вы о чем.